# Is a diffeomorphism's image automatically open?

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Sorry if this question is trivial, I am new to smooth manifold theory.

Let $\varphi : I \times \mathcal S^{n-1} \to X$ be a diffeomorphism. $I=(0,1)$, $\mathcal S^{n-1}$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$, and $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$. (The image is a sort of annulus.)

Is $X$ automatically open in $\mathbb R^n$? Is there a simple reason why it should be so?

Comment: A $n$-dimensional sub-manifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ must be open, by the inverse function theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\varphi$ being a diffeomorphism means that $X$ is such.

Comment: What manifold structure does $X$ have? Is it a submanifold? Is it arbitrary (other than cardinality) with an atlas defined to make $\phi$ a diffeomorphism? The latter makes it trivially false, so surely you must have some assumptions on $X$.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy, $\varphi : I \times \mathcal S^{n-1} \to \mathbb R^n$ is a smooth map with $X$ as its image.

Comment: Should this question be more like "Is an embedding's image automatically open?" please ? @LuizCordeiro , Yoni Rozenshein

Answer (score 1):

If $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $U$ is itself open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is Brouwer's theorem on [invariance of domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).

Comment: Should this question be more like "Is an embedding's image automatically open?" please?

Comment: @Sel No, it's not like that. It's about the specific space that is being embedded.

Comment: Thanks. But the questions are equivalent? I mean, I don't think there's much difference between $\tilde \varphi: I \times S^{n-1} \to \mathbb R^n$ such that $\tilde \varphi = \iota \circ \varphi$ for inclusion $\iota$ and $ \varphi$...

Comment: @Selene But am embedding's image is only open if the domain is homeomorphic to an open set.

Comment: How is your last comment different from your answer? Haha. It sounds like the same answer to both questions. Therefore, I think the questions are the same.