# $\left\{ (x,y,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3: y\geq 0 \right\} $ is not a 2-dimensional smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

*Claim:* $H=\left\{ (x,y,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3: y\geq 0 \right\} $ is not a $2$-dimensional smooth manifold. 
I've just started learning differential geometry, and I'm trying to prove this claim without any success. Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the edge/boundary where $y=0$, ...

Comment: Sure, but I don't see how to get a contradiction. I'm assuming it is a 2-dim manifold and there's a diffeomorphism  $f:U \rightarrow H\cap V$ for some $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ open and $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ open neighborhood of $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: @CalculClaus . The first comment to this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012616/is-a-diffeomorphisms-image-automatically-open) contains the answer to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a diffeomorphism's image automatically open?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012616/is-a-diffeomorphisms-image-automatically-open)